# I want to mask a credit card input in html. How? NO NUMBERS SHOWING AT ALL EVER. Must work with auto-complete

Tags: forms, input, credit-card

I'm trying to write html to accept credit card information without showing what the user types on the screen.

I want it replaced with black dots or asterisks.  I also want it to auto-complete from my browser's stored credit card info.  This seems so simple that I haven't been able to find it.  Help?

What I have so far:

```
<form>
<input name="cc-number" type="cc-number" autocomplete="cc-number"></input>
</form>
```

This pulls the credit card information, as expected.  But I don't know how to mask what the user sees with dots/asterisks.

How do I mask input to be dots or asterisks without EVER showing a number on the screen in my input field?

Comment: Maybe you can use [password input type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/password): `<input type="password">`

Comment: Negative.  It then no longer auto-completes for a credit card.  It attempts to auto-complete for a password.    But at least it has black dots. Thanks for the suggestion.